# Why is my .profile export being ignored?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, bash-profile

I have the following at the end of my `.profile` file on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/tom/Desktop/PACS/moos-ivp/bin

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/tom/Programs/or-tools_Ubuntu-18.04-64bit_v7.2.6977/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/sys/os/glnxa64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/runtime/glnxa64

export matlabroot=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95
```

`PATH` and `matlabroot` are available to my session after logging in, however, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` always returns empty. Unless I source the file manually.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `PATH` and `matlabroot` sourced elsewhere, e.g. in `.bashrc` file?

`~/.profile` is only sourced for interactive login shells. If you're starting a shell that's interactive, then `~/.bashrc` (or your shell of choice) is sourced.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980 for more information

Comment: No, I don't. It is only defined in .profile. The trouble I'm having is that if I define these exports elsewhere then IntelliJ/Gradle cannot see the variables. Is it possible that the multiple exports for LD_LIBRARY_PATH are causing an issue?

Comment: define them in `.profile` for IntelliJ and in your `.bashrc` for cli operation. No, multliple exports of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will not be an issue unless you export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` **later** without `MATLAB_Runtime`

Comment: I will give this a go, thank you. I am still confused as to why my terminal cannot see the LD_LIBRARY_PATH source but can see PATH and matlabroot

Comment: you must export that somewhere, possibly systemwide

Comment: @Bart: you should *not* put environment variable definitions in ~/.bashrc - those should go in ~/.profile. Indeed, the link that you provided says so (correctly).  What's happening with the OP's question is anybody's guess and putting the definition of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  in .bashrc will "fix" it, but it will hide the underlying problem that still needs to be resolved.

Comment: @NickD, fair point